# vb.net clipboard numbers gets truncated

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

I have some numbers in excel. I need to copy/past them to listview control on userform.

I'm using clipboard `Dim str As String = Clipboard.GetText` to read copied data. Problem is that numbers get truncated to part only visible in excell cell.

[image: example]

Number 2 will be pasted as 6,504 but in real it's 6,50365714285714. It's just excel formatting to show only 3 digits.
How to retrieve whole number from clipboard?

Comment: The problem is not retrieving from clipboard. The number has been truncated by Excel while copying it to the clipboard. I.e., Excel has copied the visible text to the clipboard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614910/paste-from-excel-into-c-sharp-app-retaining-full-precision

Comment: My question would be, what's the context of this?  Is the purpose of this Copy/Paste mechanic you're implementing to transfer data from existing spreadsheets?  Because if so there are a number of different approaches that are better suited

Comment: Thanks for link. This is exacly the problem that i'm facing. I'll dig into this as proposed solusion is something new for me. 
 
Hursey - Purpose is to copy/paste data from open spreadsheet to Listview control on userform.